# MySQL stored procedure error: unknown system variable

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a problem with a stored procedure in MySQL 5.5. This is the table on which the procedure must work:

```
Table `diba`:
----------------------------------------------------
Column   | Type    | Null | Default | Links to
----------------------------------------------------
ParentID | int(11) | No   |         | articoli -> id         
ChildID  | int(11) | No   |         | articoli -> id
Quantity | int(11) | No   |
lvl      | int(11) | No   | 0
```

and this is the procedure itself:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE RenumberLevels()
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE lvl_counter INT;
SET lvl_counter = 1;
UPDATE `diba` SET `diba`.`lvl` = CASE WHEN `diba`.`ParentID` IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `diba` WHERE `diba`.`lvl` = 0) DO
UPDATE `diba` SET `diba`.`lvl` = lvl_counter +1 WHERE (SELECT `D2`.`lvl` FROM `diba` AS D2
WHERE D2.ChildID = `diba`.`ParentID`) > 0 AND `diba`.`lvl` = 0;
SET `diba`.`lvl` = lvl_counter + 1;
END WHILE;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

The resulting error is:
`#1193 - Unknown system variable 'lvl'`

What's wrong with this procedure?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the line that says `SET diba.lvl = lvl_counter + 1;`? If you mean to update the column for the entire table you have to write an UPDATE statement.

Comment: I'm trying to update the 'lvl' column because it must have values ​​from 1 to 'count'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the line that says

```
SET `diba`.`lvl` = lvl_counter + 1;
```

I think you meant

```
SET lvl_counter = lvl_counter + 1;
```

Comment: In that case `lvl_counter` is `1` for the entire duration of the procedure. Is that really what you want?

Comment: You were right.. it doesn't solve my problem but i have to write an UPDATE statement or add 'lvl_counter' instead of 'diba.lvl'..

Answer (score 3):

This is the correct version of the *create procedure* statement:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `RenumberLevels`()
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  DECLARE lvl_counter INT;
  SET lvl_counter = 1;
  UPDATE `diba` SET `diba`.`lvl` = CASE WHEN `diba`.`ParentID` IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
  WHILE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM diba WHERE lvl = 0) DO
    CREATE TABLE dibatemp AS
      SELECT D2.lvl FROM diba AS D2 LEFT JOIN diba ON diba.ParentID=D2.ChildID;
    UPDATE diba
      SET lvl = lvl_counter +1 WHERE lvl IN (SELECT lvl FROM dibatemp) > 0 AND lvl = 0;
    DROP TABLE dibatemp;
    SET lvl_counter = lvl_counter + 1;
  END WHILE;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```